# Why uvm_hdl_force has effect only in interactive mode in Verdi?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am using uvm_hdl_force for various signals from my test (that extends from uvm_test). But the effect of force is only visible in INTERACTIVE mode for Verdi (VCS). How to get this work without interactive mode?
e.g.

```
class base_test extends uvm_test;
  ...
  virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    if(! uvm_hdl_force("tb.a.b.cfg", 4'h9))
      `uvm_error("TEST", "Force on tb.a.b.cfg failed")
  endtask
endclass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "-debug_all" required in VCS to use "uvm_hdl_force". you can try adding that for non-interactive run.

Comment: looks like this is related indeed. As well as -debug_access+all, i need to double check.